# How to configure PHP 5.6/Apache 2.4 in xampp(Windows 7) with Oracle oci8_11g?

Tags: php, oracle, apache, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I'm using **Xampp** environment **(PHP 5.6.21/Apache 2.4.17/MySQL 5.0)** in **windows 7 32 bit**.

I'm trying to connect to the Remote Oracle Database using Oracle Instant Client in PHP.

I can able to load the `oci8_11g` related Dll files into the application, But Oracle Run-time Client Library Version is not loading.
Here I have attached the screenshot, Kindly help me in resolving the issue.

your suggestions are appreciated.

[image: Click here to see image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really i got frustrated with oracle configuration with PHP. Finally i got the solution.
Please go through the Following steps.

1. First check your PHP version and Windows OS(32-bit or 64-bit).
2. Go to www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html.
3. Download the files which are related to your PHP and windows configuration.
4. Place the Oracle Instant Client folder in your system C:\ drive.
5. Update the PATH in the Environment Variables with your Oracle Instant Client folder path.
6. Add this line to your Apache HTTP.conf file "LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so".
7. Go to www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/ and Download the file "modules-2.4-win32-VC11.zip"
8. Extract the folder "modules-2.4-win32-VC11.zip" and find the folder with this name "mod_fcgid-2.3.9"
9. Copy the "mod_fcgid.so" file and place this file into your "C:\xampp\apache\modules".
10. Go to windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.6/" and search for "php_oci8-2.0.6-5.5-ts-vc11-x86".
11. Download the file "php_oci8-2.0.6-5.5-ts-vc11-x86" and extract this file and place them in your "C:\xampp\php\ext".
12. Go to php.ini and enable your extension "extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client"
13. Just restart your Xampp Apache and Check your oci enable or or not by browsing phpinfo();
14. Strat using your Oracle Services with PHP Application.

Hope this solution is helpful for you guys..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got Oracle libraries in your `PATH`? They can be from a database installation or from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html  You'll need 32 bit libraries if you are using 32 bit PHP.

Comment: Yes, Christopher. I downloaded 32 bit files and followed required steps for windows from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html.
But i can't able to load : Oracle Run-time Client Library Version